# I don't understand the bulid deployment package in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I don't understand how to use this feature called "Build deployment package" in VS 2010. I go to my properties and go to package/publish web and setup it up. I click "Create deployment package as zip"

I then build the deployment package and get a zip file.

When I look into and start drilling down in the folders I find I get a path like this

```
Content/C_C/Users/MyUserName/Desktop/NewFolder/Trunk/MySoultionFolder
```

I don't understand why it makes all these folders and on top of it why is it my path to where my soultion sits. I don't like the fact that now everyone can look in the zip and see my accoutn name, where the file was sitting, that I am using subversion.

Then it makes it so confusing to when a error happens. I deployed it on my IIS windows 2008 server and ran it and I had a error show up. It pointed to the file where the error occured and the path was point to my desktop.For the longest time I could not understand why it was pointing to my windows 7 machine desktop when it was running on a windows 2008 server located in a different country.

It was not until I found out with the zip path it made sense. But that is confusing when it is pointing to paths that don't exist on that computer.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command builds a deployment package that is [specific for IIS7](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618002431/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/06/25/a-practical-example-of-using-web-application-deployment-package-with-iis7.aspx).  Its meant so that a dev can build the package and hand it directly off to, say, your IT staff, who can [import the package in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/import-a-package-through-iis-manager) without having to worry too much about details of the install.

If this install method is not appropriate for you, you shouldn't use it.  For example, I usually just do a simple publish and then "xcopy" the exported files onto my already created website.

Comment: I think it is good. I am just saying I don't want the path to be my local computer. It seems so confusing when an error occurs and it is pointing to some unknown path that does not exist on the server.